# Birkhoff-von Neumann like result for stochastic matrices?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-hulls, stochastic-matrices

During my research, I came along a nice lemma which looks like a Birkhoff-Neumann-theorem result, but in a version for stochastic matrices. Namely, I have:

**Lemma.** Let $M$ be a stochastic matrix, then $M$ can be written as a convex combination of stochastic matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$.

This looks similar to the Birkhoff-Neumann-theorem and the proof is not difficult either, so I have the feeling, that this result has occurred somewhere before. Unfortunately, I did not find any concrete references for it.

Maybe it's just folklore, but can someone point me, where this result may already have appeared?

Comment: Binary stochastic matrices are permutation matrices, right?

Comment: So, your generalization is from "doubly stochastic" to "stochastic"? Where "stochastic" means nonnegative and all row sums are $1$. I think this makes it much easier to prove.  Reduce to do the case of one row.